# StarTeam Annotations?

Tags: version-control, starteam

In IntelliJ there is an option to display [annotations](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/working-with-annotations.html) (line by line history of a file); I know IntelliJ does not support StarTeam, but is there a similar way to view file line history with StarTeam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In StarTeam, you can choose two revisions of the same file (via the *History* tab) and compare them.
(I don't recall anything similar to *IntelliJ's annotations* in StarTeam)

Answer (score 1):

The StarTeam GUI client added this in a later 2008R2 version.  It is under Tools, File Annotation.  It is displayed as a separate pane in the GUI, similar to the file compare pane.